# Equality between integrable functions on a probability space and improper Riemann integral

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I have the following proof to do:

Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)\to [0,\infty]$ be integrable. Prove the following
$$\int X\,dP = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq x\})\,dx$$
where the RHS is an improper Riemann integral.

I am having trouble finding the right approach to this problem.

Comment: The [proof](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esp%C3%A9rance_math%C3%A9matique#Cas_d'une_variable_al%C3%A9atoire_r%C3%A9elle_positive) is a classic application of Fubuni--Tonelli's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write 
$$
X(\omega)=\int_0^\infty {\bf1}(x\le X(\omega))\,dx
$$
Substitute this into $\int X(\omega)\,dP$.